# Sql type to CLR type string

Tags: sql, sql-server

consider the following query

```
SELECT table_name  AS SqlColumnTableName, 
       column_name AS SqlColumnName, 
       data_type   AS SqlColumnType, 
       CASE 
         WHEN is_nullable = 'YES' THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END         AS IsNullable, 
       CASE 
         WHEN numeric_scale = 0 THEN 'Int' 
         WHEN Isnull(numeric_precision, 0) > 0 THEN 'Decimal' 
         WHEN Isnull(datetime_precision, 0) > 0 THEN 'DateTime' 
         WHEN character_set_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'String' 
         WHEN data_type = 'bit' THEN 'Bool' 
       END         AS CLR_Type, 
       CASE 
         WHEN column_name IN(SELECT column_name 
                             FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END         AS IsPrimaryKey 
FROM   information_schema.columns
```

with this query i get some info about a column including its name and its table name and if its a primary key column, however i am trying to find a good way to produce a string depending on the sql type of the column as you can see in this case statement

```
CASE 
  WHEN numeric_scale = 0 THEN 'Int' 
  WHEN Isnull(numeric_precision, 0) > 0 THEN 'Decimal' 
  WHEN Isnull(datetime_precision, 0) > 0 THEN 'DateTime' 
  WHEN character_set_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'String' 
  WHEN data_type = 'bit' THEN 'Bool' 
END AS CLR_Type,
```

- float,money,real and any type that can represended as decimal shall produce 'Decimal'
- nvarchar,ncchar,text and anytype that represents a string shall
  produce 'String'
- datetime,date shall produce 'DateTime'
- Int shall produce an 'Int'
- bit shall produce a 'Bool'

is there a more convenient way than the one i suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a small table that maps DATA_TYPE to CLR_TYPE using [SQL-CLR Type Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DefaultTypeMapping) and join against that.  It shouldn't be much cutting and pasting to get all of the types.

Watch out for [SQL-CLR Type Mismatches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386909%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, are you sure you don't want to use LINQ for this?  You may be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: i am generating the sql queries using a graphical interface, so i need it to work that way, but i get your suggestion ive chosen to do it fast and ignored the accurcy

Comment: by using linq you mean entity frameork? what i am trying to do is get the sql column schema and convert it to an object